# Unable to run a device in GenyMotion emulator

Tags: arch-linux, android

I have installed GenyMotion and its dependencies(Virtual Box, ...) from AUR.
Now I'm trying to run a device in GenyMotion emulator but gets me following error:

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine. Make sure that you have installed it
>   correctly before starting Genymotion. For more information refer to:
>   https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#vbox

[image]

**P.S :**

You can see the log content in `~/.Genymobile/genymotion-player.log` :

```
Jan 7 13:19:58 [Genymotion Player] [Error] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 1 
Jan 7 13:19:58 [Genymotion Player] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp"
```

Comment: Do you have `vboxnetctl` under `/dev` directory?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: So perhaps something wrong with your vbox installation. Try to restart it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1671

Comment: Or this: http://www.stumiller.me/fixing-vagrant-osx-mavericks-update/

Comment: I tried all above links but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Arch Linux try :

```
$ sudo vboxreload
```

And for Mac try :

```
$ sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Comment: this is some serious magic

Comment: i get same error on arch still.